# How to get Kakaotalk API for Android application ?

Tags: android, api, sdk

I want to build a android application with Kakao integration. My application require these functionality.

1. Login with Kakaotalk account.
2. Fetching friends list of a user.
3. Can post a message to a user (fetched in step 2).

So does kakao provides an api or sdk like facebook sdk. Can we implement functionality in our own application without launching Kakaotalk application and sending data to it using intent ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got my answer from kakao support that they do not provide any SDK or API to fetch friends.So  it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Now days KakaoTalk REST API has such example to fetching user list on their page

```
curl -v -X GET https://kapi.kakao.com/v1/user/ids \
      -H "Authorization: KakaoAK kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk"
```

[link to REST API](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&sl=auto&tl=destination_language&u=https://developers.kakao.com/docs/restapi#%EC%82%AC%EC%9A%A9%EC%9E%90-%EA%B4%80%EB%A6%AC-%EC%82%AC%EC%9A%A9%EC%9E%90-%EB%A6%AC%EC%8A%A4%ED%8A%B8-%EC%9A%94%EC%B2%AD)

Answer (score 0):

You will get kakao talk library & basic usage details on github. Check out below mentioned link
https://github.com/kakao/kakaolink-android
Hope this will help your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Kakao provides Android SDK that includes the function of retrieving the friends list.
https://developers.kakao.com/docs/latest/en/kakaotalk-social/android#get-friends